# Android Dialog error The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to give data to my listView, When clicking FAB then it shows a dialog box with one editText and two buttons. In first time it allow me to give data to ListView. but when I try second time it shows the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>   Process: com.example.app.wounderlist.wounderlist, PID: 3790 
>                                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: **The** **specified** **child** **already** **has** **a** **parent**. **You** **must** **call** **removeView()** **on** **the** **child's** **parent** **first.**
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupCustomContent(AlertController.java:647)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:463)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:226)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
>                                                                                              at com.example.app.wounderlist.wounderlist.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:79)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

## And here is my code

```
//create a dialog box with a editText and a Add button when pressing the #FAB
        final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(getActivity());
        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Add a new task")
                        .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                        .setView(taskEditText)
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //for getting text from the editText
                                String itemText = taskEditText.getText().toString();
                                mItemsAdapter.add(itemText);


                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you use your taskEditText somewhere else ?

Comment: no I am only use it in setView(taskEditText); and at String itemText = taskEditText.getText().toString(); only

Comment: You have to put the edittext in a layout ... like relative or linear, or frame ... then add to alertdialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of the `AlertDialog` every button click. Create a final `AlertDialog` outside of the `OnClickListener` inner class.

try this:

```
 final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(getActivity());
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder1.setMessage("What do you want to do next?");
builder1.setCancelable(true);

builder1.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                //for getting text from the editText
                                String itemText = taskEditText.getText().toString();
                                mItemsAdapter.add(itemText);

                            }
                        });

builder1.setNegativeButton(
   "Cancel", null);

AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();

 mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               alert11.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(getActivity());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder1.setMessage("What do you want to do next?");

        //I add this extra code to get the EditText
        builder1.setView(taskEditText);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //for getting text from the editText
                String itemText = taskEditText.getText().toString();
                mItemsAdapter.add(itemText);

                //And I also add this code to clear the editText
                taskEditText.setText("");

            }
        });

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "Cancel", null);

        final AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alert11.show();
            }
        });
```

## Finally I got the answer

## thanks to all and especially to @rafsanahmad007

Happy Coding!!